# How can I write data from a C# app into GE Proficy Historian

Tags: historian, proficy

I would like to use GE Proficy Historian to archive data from instruments that are not connected to a PLC.  Can this be done using c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Historian c# User API wrapper to access and update Historian from c#. There is information available on it in the Historian documentation that installs with the client tools. Updating Historian with data from non-PLC connected devices is counterintuitive though, as you have the data elsewhere (I assume) and Historian is designed to log activity from PLCs and similar devices.

It will probably be more difficult to read data from non-PLC connected devices into c# than to write data to Historian.

Answer (score 1):

Using Historian File collector (historian File Collector is the service available on the machine where Histoiran Server has been installed), we can write data into Proficy Historian.
Step 1. Verify Histoarian File Collector Service is started.
Step 2. Locate the folder :\Proficy Historian Data\ImportFiles\Incoming.(On server)
Step 3. Write a program to crate csv file. Write date in following syntax in that file.
Syntax : Tagname,TimeStamp,Value,DataQuality
Example TIGER.IMPORT_TAG1.F_CV,7/20/01 11:07,1,Good
Step 4. create this csv file on lication mentioned above.

Historian file collector will automatically process this csv file and file will be moved to Processed folder available on same lication. If csv file has some error it will be available move to error folder. csv file moved to Processed folder indicates the data is written to historian tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options:

1. Use the User API interface via ihuapi.dll. This is a bit easier now that GE provides DLL import and struct definitions, but it can still be a bit daunting. It will work though. Actually, it works quite well.
2. Use the SDK interface via ihsdk.dll. This is actually a bit easier to work with as compared to the User API. The SDK is a COM library so it has to be registered on the machine.
3. If the instrument is OPC compliant you can use the OPC collector to forward the data directly to the server; no coding necessary.
4. Starting with 5.0 the Collector Toolkit is provided free of charge with the install. I cannot comment to much on this yet since I have not worked with custom collectors very much.